# Automatic SyntaxHighlighter with Prettify

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, syntax-highlighting, prettify, pagedown

Working on a school project where we have creating a forum based website. We are using [PageDown](https://github.com/timmyomahony/pagedown) and [Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) to handle the text.
 but like it's now we have to use `<!--?prettify?-->`on the code to get it out nice and smooth, but are there some way we can tell the program to handle all `<pre>`tags from PageDown automatic with prettify?

Are there some disadvantage to have automatic SyntaxHighlighter?

### 1# Possible solution, but not what i had in mind:

You can add `$("pre").addClass("prettyprint");` to javascript. This code will give every pre tag the prettyprint class, but this short code will not work in Markdown preview so for me this is only a 50% solution.

### 2# Possible solution on preview, but not user friendly:

I have found out that you can call a function `prettyPrint();` to highlight all the `<pre>`tags with `class="prettyprint"`. So if we combined solution on with this and add a `setInterval()`(or something else like `.click`) to make calls we will get something that work with Markdown preview. I believe this way is not user friendly because it's using alot of computer power (I think) and if you watch closely you can see a little flicker sometimes in the `<pre>` tags.
This is the code:

```
var timer = setInterval(prettytimer, 0);

function prettytimer() {
    $("pre").addClass("prettyprint");
    prettyPrint();
};
```

If someone wondering why there is no `.removeClass()` or `hasClass()` check, that's because `.addClass()` doesn't add same class twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 3# solution i went for:

This is the solution i went for in the preview handler site and solution **1#** on rest of the web-page. There might be some better ways but this way will give you the Stack Overflow feeling.

```
var timer;

//If the code button have been pressed {}
$("#wmd-code-button").click(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(prettytimer, 3000);
});

//when on key have been released inside textarea
$(".wmd-input").on("keyup", function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(prettytimer, 3000);
});

//If `timer` reach 3000 (3 seconds) execute this
function prettytimer() {
    $("pre").addClass("prettyprint");
    prettyPrint();
};
```

If you are using `pageDown Markdown` then you don't have to make any changes to this code, just copy it inside your javascript file :)